# Using jquery to calculate height of an element that contains another with a margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to calculate the size of a div. Jquery has a handy function for that, which is `outerHeight()`. That gives you the element's size, and if you want to include the margins, you call `outerHeight(true)`.

But. If the inner elements have a margin, the outer element's size doesn't change. Even though the inner one is still considered to be completely within. [Here's an example of what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/h8uvyx1w/).

The outer div has an outerHeight of 18, and the inner one has an outerHeight of 218, which is 18 of the text, and two 100px margins.

I can't keep track of all the things that will be inside of my final div. How can I measure its actual height, including the margins of content contained within?

Comment: Use padding instead of margin ;) https://jsfiddle.net/h8uvyx1w/1/

Comment: I'd love to but I don't get to choose that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit hacky way, but you can add

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

This will force the container to get the correct height.

```js
document.write('container height= ' + $("#container").outerHeight(true) + '<br>');
document.write('stuff height= ' + $("#stuff").outerHeight(true));
```

```css
#stuff {
  margin: 100px;
}
#container {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p id="stuff">
    lorem ipsum and so on
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic. This actually works. I still have no idea why outerHeight won't calculate the entire height without adding the transparent border but thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider your css a bad practice and change it. E.g. you could wrap the inner div and give the wrapper a padding instead of the margin.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p id="stuff">
      lorem ipsum and so on
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
  padding: 100px;
}
#stuff {
  margin: 0;
}
```

I updated your example: https://jsfiddle.net/h8uvyx1w/2/

Or perhaps you don't need the wrapper, if you can change the inner divs margin to padding, depending on your needs.

Comment: Oh please. And I consider answering a question that wasn't asked bad practice. No, I can't change that. I still need to figure out the height of a div that contains things that I may not necessarily have control over or be able to predict.

Comment: You didn't state that in your question, so I only knew that you can't change the content inside the div, therefore it is a valid option to wrap it in another div. Moreover I didn't say that it *is* bad practice, I just added my opinion, so you can take that into consideration. No offense meant by that! I'm glad you figured it out with dimshiks answer.

Comment: How could I possibly "calculate height of an element that contains another with a margin" if the contained element doesn't have a margin?